# Debugging AVL Tree Deletion: Unbalanced Node Not on Deletion Path

Tags: database, algorithm, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

I'm working on implementing an AVL tree in C++, and I've run into a situation where, after deleting a node and rebalancing the tree, a node not directly on the path from the deleted node to the root becomes unbalanced. I've walked through my deletion and rebalancing algorithm, but I can't seem to identify the problem.

Here's the initial AVL tree state before any operations:

[image: inital AVL]

I want to delete the node with the value "914". According to my algorithm, I proceed with the deletion and then perform the necessary rotations to rebalance the tree. However, after the deletion and rebalancing process, I end up with an unbalanced node that wasn't a direct ancestor of the deleted node.

Here's the tree after deletion and rebalancing operations:

1. after deleting:

[image: after deleting]

2. balancing the node that replaces the deleted one:

[image: balancing the node that replaces the deleted one]

3. balancing the root - part a:

[image: balancing the root - part a]

4. balancing the root - part b:

[image: balancing the root - part b]

My algorithm updates the heights and balances after every rotation, and it seems to follow the correct AVL deletion process. However, it ends up with node "381" being unbalanced, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: If my recollection on AVL trees is correct, a valid, stable (outside of a pending insert or delete) tree can never have a difference of more than one node between its left and right sub-trees, so your initial tree seems to already be invalid.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, the initial tree is valid. AVL trees don't balance the *number* of nodes, but the *heights*: the height difference of two sibling subtrees (i.e. the balance factor at the parent node) should not exceed 1.

Comment: Oh, that’s right, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the first rotation you apply to balance the root (part a): this rotation is not called for. It would only be needed if the left child of the root would be *right heavy*. But it isn't. And so you shouldn't perform that "part a", but only apply a single rotation at the root to the right.

Here is the whole sequence from the starting point:

```
             ___720___
            /         \
       ___381__       914
      /        \      / \
   _169_       459  735 915
  /     \      / \    \
159     272  426 561  783
  \     / \      / \
  165 218 286  537 717
```

After deletion of 914

```
             ___720___
            /         \
       ___381__       915
      /        \      /
   _169_       459  735
  /     \      / \    \
159     272  426 561  783
  \     / \      / \
  165 218 286  537 717
```

Node 915 is not balanced: as its left child is right-heavy, we need a double rotation (first 735 to the left, then 915 to the right):

```
             ___720___
            /         \
       ___381__       783
      /        \      / \
   _169_       459  735 915 
  /     \      / \
159     272  426 561
  \     / \      / \
  165 218 286  537 717
```

Node 720 is not balanced. But here the left child of 720 is not right-heavy, so we need a **single** rotation of 720 to the right:

```
       ______381_____
      /              \
   _169_            _720_
  /     \          /     \
159     272      459     783 
  \     / \      / \     / \
  165 218 286  426 561 735 915 
                   / \
                 537 717
```

And now the tree is balanced.

Comment: Any feedback to this answer?